# Parallel resistor and current source analysis

Tags: capacitor, resistors, dc, parallel, current-source

I'm a little bit confused by this circuit. I want to analyse the current "I"s AC and DC terms.
Since the capacitor will allow AC, there will be an output current Iout which is the sum of Ir and I, making **I = Iout - Ir**. For DC, there will not be any output current because the capacitor will block it. The resistor and the current source will be in series, and thus the current "I" will be the current through the resistor. However, the direction of the current "I" and the current that goes from Vs to 0V are opposing each other. How am I supposed to approach for DC analysis? Thank you for advance :)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fhfl9O.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: One of the two will be negative.

Comment: If you are trying to find Ir for the DC analysis, and by going of the direction of current, you would get an equation of I+Ir=0 -> I=-Ir. This means that the value of Ir should be a negative value to represent the current going the other direction, opposite of which the arrow is pointing. It doesn't matter which direction you draw the arrows to represent current what matters is the current value to indicate direction with respect to the arrow